# Is it possible to predict number of edges in a strongly connected directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory

### I know the following:

A graph that is **complete** and **undirected** with $n$ nodes will have $n(n-1)/2$ edges

A graph that is **complete** and **directed** with $n$ nodes will have $n(n-1)$ edges

A graph that is **connected (without cycles)** and **undirected** with $n$ nodes will have $(n-1)$ edges

### My questions are:

1. A graph that is **strongly connected (without cycles)** and **directed** with $n$ nodes will have $?$ edges
2. A graph that is **strongly connected (with cycles)** and **directed** with $n$ nodes will have $?$ edges

I am not sure about the last two. Could someone help shed some light and provide an analytic form for them as well as provide an explanation why this is the case?

### My attempts are:

1. The answer is impossible because we need cycles in a directed graph to make it strongly connected. (This is a gut feeling that I am failing to articulate into actual formal mathematical reasoning)
2. The answer is simply $2(n-1)$. (This is a gut feeling that I am failing to articulate into actual formal mathematical reasoning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your gut feeling is right:

   - A cycle is a sequence $v_1, v_2, ... v_k$ of vertices such that: $v_1 = v_k$, and there is a directed edge between $v_i$ and  $v_{i+1}$ for $i \in [1, k-2]$.
   - A graph is said to be strongly connected or diconnected if every vertex is reachable from every other vertex. In particular, $v_2$ is reachable from $v_1$ and $v_1$ is reachable from $v_2$, which means that there is a cycle in the graph.
2. A (directed) cycle graph with $n$ vertices and $n$ edges is strongly connected. Conversely, any graph with $n-1$ edges is not strongly connected. Furthermore, the complete graph is strongly connected. So a strongly connected graph with $n$ nodes will have between $n$ and $n(n-1)$ edges.

Comment: Just to clarify `A (directed) cycle graph with n vertices and n edges is strongly connected` means `if I have n edges (distinct) I am guaranteed strong connectivity` not `maybe` right?

Comment: Sorry I wasen't clear. There exists a strongly connected graph with only $n$ edges: $(v_1, v_2)$, $(v_2, v_3)$, ... $(v_n, v_1)$. However there also exist graphs with $n$ edges that are not connected (and therefore not strongly connected).